# Software to measure true distances on images on linux

Tags: linux, images

Suppose you have an image of a real object which contains also a measuring stick (or another objekt of exactly known length).

Now I am looking for a software where I can measure the real distances betweeen any two points of the picture after setting a calibration stick to the measuring stick (like in [tracker](http://physlets.org/tracker/), but just for pictures, not for videos) on the picture.

Clearly I can measure the pixels in gimp and make the calculation manually. But is there any tool which does it automatically?

Comment: According to [Tracker's documentation](http://www.cabrillo.edu/~dbrown/tracker/help/gettingstarted.html#open), you can also open still images (jpg, gif, png).

Comment: I don't understand how this would be possible (assuming that by “image” you mean a 2D picture taken by an ordinary camera). The distance between objects represented in the picture would depend on their depths.

Comment: @Gilles Sure, however, if you have two objects in the same 2D plane (orthogonal to the lens direction), then the scale is retained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Tracker

[Tracker](https://physlets.org/tracker/) is an open-source video analysis software aimed at tracking coordinates of moving objects in videos. As part of this feature, it includes measuring tools, which allow to measure a distance between two points in a frame (or over the course of multiple frames) after having set a calibration stick.

Matched requirements:

- Apart from video files, Tracker handles still images (JPEG, GIF, PNG) as well (cf. [its documentation](https://physlets.org/tracker/help/gettingstarted.html#open)).
- It runs on Windows, Mac OS X, Linux 32-bit and Linux 64-bit.

Comment: For Linux there is only the Beta version.

Answer (score 4):

### GIMP

You can measure real distances (in mm, cm, m and so on) in GIMP as follows:

1. Select the [Measure Tool](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tool-measure.html).
2. Measure the reference element of known size in pixels, and calibrate the image resolution under "Image → Print size …" accordingly.

   For example, when your reference element measures 100 pixels and is 35 mm long, you enter into the boxes "X resolution" and "Y resolution: 100/35 pixels/mm. Just enter it as "100/35", GIMP will do the calculation for you.
3. In the status bar on the bottom left of the image, change the unit from pixels to something else.

   [image]
4. In the tool options, there is also the checkbox "Use info window". This will show a small overlay window (or real window if you like). Unlike the status bar, you can select the measurement results here and copy them to the clipboard.

Comment: In step 2, I can't set print size to μm... Is there another way to calibrate the measure tool?

Answer (score 1):

Try https://www.pdftron.com/pdf-tools/pdf-measurement/
You have to upload the image and you also get loads of options including scaling the screen distance to the actual distance shown in the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

For simple 2D measurement of images you can try [Micalibre](https://artstn.co/m/VVxd). It's a paid app but is available for Windows and Linux. It's simple to use, load an image, use a known distance in order to calibrate it and start taking measurements of distances, angles, polygons areas, etc.

PS: Just to be clear, I'm the developer of the app.

Comment: As a link only answer, it could get deleted. Please provide more details on it. And you are required to declare your affiliation to it.